# How to use multiple conditions in IIF expressions in ssrs to return a value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am a beginner in SSRS and maybe this may sound easy, I have a dataset like below.

[image]

What I want to achieve is:

[image]

For column `region` and `country` I used a `Row Groups`. For column `New lead` I used this `expression` `=IIF(Fields!TextA.Value=Fields!TextB.Value AND Fields!Subject.Value = "New Lead" AND NOT(Fields!Category.Value = "Closed"), Fields!Total.Value + 1, nothing)` to get `Total` value for each `Subject` and just change the harcoded value for `Fields!Subject.Value` for Column `Contract, Qualify` but the value is not populated. I Checked there is no typo for hardcoded value. I can achieved this by using matrix but the columns arrangement for `new Lead, Contract and Qualify` is not like I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking programmatically and adding the total one by one.

```
Fields!Total.Value + 1
```

You want to **SUM** the Totals if it matches the given Subject (and A = B and Not Closed).

```
=SUM(
    IIF(Fields!TextA.Value = Fields!TextB.Value AND Fields!Subject.Value = "New Lead" AND NOT(Fields!Category.Value = "Closed")
        , Fields!Total.Value, 0))
```

Are TextA and TextB always the same? If so, you can remove that part.

You're probably also going to need to Group By your Area to make it look like your mock-up - otherwise Thailand would sum up Bangkok and Phuket.